# are there any faults in the following code revision (PHP)

Tags: php

since undefined equates to false, i am wondering if there are any draw backs to replacing the following code:

```
    public static function user_access_level() {
        if (isset($_SESSION['lev_user_access'])) {
            return $_SESSION['lev_user_access'];
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

with:

```
    public static function user_access_level() {
        return $_SESSION['lev_user_access'];
    }
```

Comment: Better suited for: http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will get a warning, if you have `E_WARNING` (or `E_ALL`, which you should be coding with).

> Notice: Undefined index:  lev_user_access in /your-script.php on line 7

You could use a ternary operator...

```
return isset($_SESSION['lev_user_access']) ? $_SESSION['lev_user_access'] : FALSE ;
```

Comment: +1 for writing php code that doesn't generate warnings and notices.

Answer (score 1):

false !== null
but false == null

You'll also get problems if $_SESSION['lev_user_access'] is undefined (a notice will be reported depending on your error_level settings and display_errors setting.

if you want to do a one liner:

```
public static function user_access_level() {
    return (isset($_SESSION['lev_user_access'])) ? $_SESSION['lev_user_access']:false;
}
```

which may be more acceptable, but some, including myself, would argue that it's not as simple to read.